# How to specify and change the program name in Windows 7 Jumplist?

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-7, jump-list

In the following example, where to specify and change the program name "T"?

Once I run the program, there is no way to change the display name in jumplist even I modify the product name to something else such as "X".

I changed AssemblyTitle but jumplist is not updated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You changed the title in the right place, but it seems that Windows caches somehow the assembly title for a .exe file. If you also change your Assembly Name it would invalidate the cache and the new title shows up in the jumplist. I am not sure how to clear the assembly cache (without changing the assembly name).